# Не работает range slider и formstyler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```js
$(function () {

   $('.menu__btn').on('click', function () {
      $('.menu__btn').toggleClass('menu__btn--active');
      $('.menu__list').toggleClass('menu__list--active');
   });

   $('.search').on('click', function () {
      $('.menu__search').toggleClass('menu__search--active');
   });

   $('.minicard__heart').on('click', function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
   });

   $('.minicard__srav').on('click', function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
   });

   //стилизация select
   $('select').styler();
   //стилизация select

   //range slider
   var custom_values = [0, "500T", "800T", "1.1M", "1.4M", "1.7M", "2M", "2.3M", "2.7M", "3M"];
   var my_from = custom_values.indexOf("500T");
   var my_to = custom_values.indexOf("1.7M");

   $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
      skin: "round",
      type: "double",
      grid: true,
      from: my_from,
      to: my_to,
      values: custom_values
   });
   //range slider

   //range slider
   var custom_values = [6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84];
   var my_from = custom_values.indexOf(24);
   var my_to = custom_values.indexOf(60);

   $(".js-range-slider-mounth").ionRangeSlider({
      skin: "round",
      type: "double",
      grid: true,
      from: my_from,
      to: my_to,
      values: custom_values
   });
   //range slider

   $('.top__slider').slick({
      dots: true,
      nextArrow: '<button class="top__slider-btn top__slider-btnnext "><img src="images/arrow-right-top-slider.svg" alt=""></button>',
      prevArrow: '<button class="top__slider-btn top__slider-btnprev "><img src="images/arrow-left-top-slider.svg" alt=""></button>',
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 3000,
      responsive: [
         {
            breakpoint: 1300,
            settings: {
               arrows: false
            }
         }
      ]
   });

   $('.selection__slider').slick({
      nextArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnnext"><img src="images/arrow-right-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      prevArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnprev "><img src="images/arrow-left-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      responsive: [
         {
            breakpoint: 1401,
            settings: "unslick"
         }
      ]
   });

   $('.special-offers__slider').slick({
      nextArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnnext"><img src="images/arrow-right-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      prevArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnprev "><img src="images/arrow-left-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      responsive: [
         {
            breakpoint: 1401,
            settings: "unslick"
         }
      ]
   });

   $('.partners__slider').slick({
      nextArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnnext"><img src="images/arrow-right-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      prevArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnprev "><img src="images/arrow-left-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      responsive: [
         {
            breakpoint: 1501,
            settings: "unslick"
         }
      ]
   });

   $('.trust__slider').slick({
      nextArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnnext"><img src="images/arrow-right-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      prevArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnprev "><img src="images/arrow-left-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      responsive: [
         {
            breakpoint: 1501,
            settings: "unslick"
         }
      ]
   });

   $('.blog__slider').slick({
      nextArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnnext"><img src="images/arrow-right-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      prevArrow: '<button class="selection__slider-button selection__slider-btnprev "><img src="images/arrow-left-select-slider.png" alt=""></button>',
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      responsive: [
         {
            breakpoint: 1501,
            settings: "unslick"
         }
      ]
   });

   //выпадающая информация reviews
   $(".more").on('click', function () {
      $(this).prev("p.more-content").slideToggle("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
   });
   //выпадающая информация reviews

   // табы
   $('.js-tab-trigger').on('click', function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-tab'),
         content = $('.js-tab-content[data-tab="' + id + '"]');

      $('.js-tab-trigger.active').removeClass('active'); // 1
      $(this).addClass('active'); // 2

      $('.js-tab-content.active').removeClass('active'); // 3
      content.addClass('active'); // 4
   });
   // табы


   //изменение текста у plaseholder search
   $('.menu__search-form-search').each(function () {
      $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
   });

   function changePlaceholder() {
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
         $('.menu__search-form-search').attr('placeholder', 'Поиск автомобилей');
      } else {
         $('.menu__search-form-search').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
         });
      }
   }
   $(window).resize(changePlaceholder).trigger('resize');
   //изменение текста у plaseholder search

});
```

У меня случилась проблема которую не могу решить.
Все плагины и scriptы работают правильно, но
не работает range slider и formstyler тут
https://koljatru.github.io/autos/
Хотя у меня в VS code на live serve
re все работает правильно! Сборка Gulp.
У меня уже есть проект где все работало.
rangeslider и formstyler я установил через npm, закинул в папки файлы css и js скрин прилагаю. В gulpfile.js ничего не менял с прошлого проекта.
В чем может быть проблема? подскажите пожалуйста!
Где я делаю ошибку не пойму?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Autos</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.formstyler.theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.formstyler.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.formstyler.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: скорей всего стандартная проблема: live-сборка делается правильно, а дистрибутив нет. откройте консоль в браузере и посмотрите ошибки: какой файл найти не может, что падает в javascript и т.д. причина - самописный сборщик, вместо того, чтобы взять готовый работающий gulp-скрипт.

Comment: Алексей спасибо за ответ. Выдает 404 ошибку на файлы  ion.rangeSlider.min.js, jquery.formstyler.min.js, ion.rangeSlider.min.css, jquery.formstyler.theme.css, jquery.formstyler.css. Что с ними сделать надо?

Comment: ну смотрите, у вас есть сборка для разработки, там одна конфигурация папок (с обращением к node_modules, которой естественно нет в дистрибутиве). в дистрибутиве у вас лежит ваш html, css и js. а внешние библиотеки (на которые ругается браузер) кто будет класть в папку с дистрибутивом? я не специалист по сборщикам, но все новички всегда задают один и тот же вопрос: как это возможно, что debug работает, release нет? обратите внимание, что все эти файлы (jquery, rangeslider, formstyler) неизменны. вы можете скопировать их один раз в соседнюю и подкладывать в то место, где они ищутся.

Comment: Алексей, я изменил тело вопроса. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Может у вас получиться пошагово подсказать что надо сделать. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: вижу в логах при открытия [сайта](https://koljatru.github.io/autos/) ошибку: $(...).styler is not a function. к сожалению исходников в вашем [репозитории](https://github.com/koljatru/autos) не вижу. по минифицированным js достаточно трудно сказать, в чем дело. судя по всему, проблему со сборкой вы решили (ну или пока временно решили руками файлы подложить), но есть ошибка в main.js.

Comment: Последовательность кода, синтаксическая ошибка???Вставил код из main.js.

Comment: еще раз посмотрел ваш репозиторий. раньше времени порадовался, что вы решили проблему со сборкой. посмотрите папочки css и js. они содержат только style.min.css и main.min.js. при этом на главной странице у вас идет обращение к файлам ion.rangeSlider.min.css, jquery.formstyler.theme.css, jquery.formstyler.css, jquery.formstyler.min.js, ion.rangeSlider.min.js из этих папок. откройте закладку Сеть в инструментах разработчика и сами убедитесь: полно ресурсов со статусом 404

Comment: снова возращаемся на шаг назад и правим gulpfile.js (в нем нужно копировать нужные библиотеки в js и css папки)

Comment: Огромное спасибо Алексей. Именно так и поступил в gulpfile.js дописал подключение js файлов для этих плагинов. И еще в одном файле подключил css файлы. И все заработало! Очень вам благодарен! https://koljatru.github.io/autos/